# Access all tables from assets

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLITE file in my assets folder and in that file i have many tables.
I want to access a particular data from a particular table , how should i do that?
I am new to this so any tutorial from the scratch would be grateful?
I have read questions on this they were only for one table.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer following site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Comment: If your database is packaged in `assets/`, [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to unpack it into internal storage.

Comment: I have one table name is firstList and containing some data in that so i want to take that as we do like manually. so can we do this from assets?